# Pygame mouse button work on one click

Tags: python, button, while-loop, click, pygame

I have read the other articles on this problem and I still do not understand them. I just want my button to execute when it is pressed once not when I have to hold it down. I have the button in a while loop and the first time around it works fine but then on the second time it does not work. My code is here. Thank you for any help as my code is poorly written as I am very new and this is hard to understand to anyone other than me.

```
def newRound():
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if 730 < pos[0] < 850 and 650 < pos[1] < 800:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (150,150,150), (730,650,120,50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            startGame() 

while intro == 1:            
    if endRound == True:
        Background.blit(mapImg, (0,0))
        newRound()
        text()

    if startRound == True:
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.update()
        Background.blit(mapImg, (0,0))
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw(Background)
```

Full code with unimportant bits

```
import pygame

def text():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 14)
    text = font.render("Start Round", True, black)
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (790,675)
    Background.blit(text, textpos)

def newRound():
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    print(click)
    if 730 < pos[0] < 850 and 650 < pos[1] < 800:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (150,150,150), (730,650,120,50))
        if click[0] == 1:
            startGame()          
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(Background, (100,100,100), (730,650,120,50))

def startGame():
    global startRound, endRound, intro, whichRound
    intro = 0       
    createRound()
    intro = 1
    startRound = True
    endRound = False

def life(self):
    global hit, endRound, startRound
    if self.rect.x == 960:
        hit = hit + 1
    if hit == 6:
        startRound = False
        endRound = True

def createRound():
    x = -80
    y = 210
    for e in range(6):
        x = x - 80
        enemies.append(RedEnemy(x, y, Background))

class RedEnemy(object):

    image1 = pygame.image.load("enemySpriteFullHealth.jpg")
    image2 = pygame.image.load("enemySpriteHalfHealth.jpg")
    image3 = pygame.image.load("enemySpriteDead.jpg")

    def __init__(self, x, y, Background):
        self.Background = Background
        self.Background_rect = Background.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image1.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.health = 20
        self.dist_x = 2
        self.dist_y = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.dist_x
        self.rect.y += self.dist_y
    def draw(self, Background):
        Background.blit(self.image1, self.rect)
        life(self)

pygame.init()

width = 960
height = 720

black = (0,0,0)
lifes = 30
hit = 0
intro = 1
enemies = []
FPS = 200

endRound = True
startRound = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
mapImg = pygame.image.load("mapimage.jpg")
Background = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
Background_rect = Background.get_rect()

while intro == 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == quit:
            pygame.quit()

    if endRound == True:
        Background.blit(mapImg, (0,0))
        newRound()
        text()

    if startRound == True:
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.update()
        Background.blit(mapImg, (0,0))
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.draw(Background)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: BTW: you need `pygame.QUIT` instead of `quit` in `event.type == pygame.QUIT`

Comment: BTW: see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - use `lower_case` names for variable - ie. `background` instead od `Background`, `end_round` instead of `endRound`, ettc.

Comment: use `print()` to check what values you have in variables and which part of code is executed - probably it does not what you expect.

Comment: Thank you furas for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button works ... but you have problem with moving enemies and it looks like button doesn't work.

You move enemies till you get `hit == 6` and when you click button again then `hit` is already `6` so `hit == 6` ends moving enemies and you don't see it.

So you need

```
if hit == 6:
    startRound = False
    endRound = True
    hit = 0
```

or use different element to check when to end round.

---

When you ends moving enemies you don't remove them from list `enemies` and when you click button again you add new enemies to list and you have more and more enemies on list. Check `len(enemies)`. ie.

```
def createRound():
    x = -80
    y = 210
    for e in range(6):
        x = x - 80
        enemies.append(RedEnemy(x, y, Background))
    print('enemies:', len(enemies))
```

So clear list before you use it again

```
def createRound():
    global enemies

    enemies = []

    x = -80
    y = 210
    for e in range(6):
        x = x - 80
        enemies.append(RedEnemy(x, y, Background))
    print('enemies:', len(enemies))
```

---

BTW: you could use `intro = True` instead of `intro = 1`. And `while intro:` instead of `while intro == 1:`. It is more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much this has helped me a lot